# Error accesing configure service account page in central admin

Tags: iis, application-pool

recently i migrated sharepoint farm from one domain to another. i manually changed application pool identity in IIS which is bad practice which i later realized. now that i read some articles and get to know that, best practice to do it using configure service accounts through central administraion. when i try to access that link, i get error

```
Some or all identity references could not be translated.
```

any idea of resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

As per your description looks like you still have reference old domain's service account...

Check the Managed Services account(from Central Admin) and make no old domain account showed here.

run the below powershell to remove it.`[Remove-SPManagedAccount][1] -Identity DOMAIN\ServiceAcct`

And

Also try to add your service account using this powershell.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
New-SPManagedAccount -Credential $cred
```